# Range Queries in Lucene

Tags: php, lucene

I am using Lucene with PHP to build my search engine. Now each document of index has three fields: `title`, `startTime` and `finishTime`. With the PHP web interface I can know the user's current time. In response to the user query I want the documents to be retrieved if and only if user's current time is between the `startTime` and `finishTime` field of that retrieved document.

I am new to Lucene. So I would like to know is there any way in Lucene I can do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure that `startTime` and `finishTime` are integer values, ideally the numeric UNIX time or a tick-count. If you use a string date representation like "MM/dd/yyyy" then it won't work.

Your query can be rephrased as "where startTime is less than now, and finishTime is greater than now". This can be converted into Lucene's query syntax like so (where `555` is the current timestamp value):

```
startTime:[0 TO 555] AND finishTime:[555 TO 999]
```

(where `0` and `999` are the minimum and maximum bound values respectively)

Note that if you're adding other terms you'll want to group these two range predicates with parentheses, and also note that Lucene defaults to "OR" instead of "AND".

A syntax reference is available here: http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Range%20Searches

In PHP you'd do it like this:

```
$userTime = getUserTime(); // this must be an integer numeric value.
$max = mktime(23,59,59, 12,31,2099); // generates an upperbound timestamp

$query = "startTime:[0 TO %1$d] AND finishTime:[%1$d TO %2$d]";
$query = sprintf($query, $userTime, $max);
```

Then submit `$query` to your Lucene search.

Comment: Sir, you mean userTime is also of same format as unix timestamp. But Sir, in the database those timings i.e. startTime and finishTime is fixed and of the format hh:mm, say, startTime=10:00 am and finishTime=12:00 am. So at the time of query I also have to convert those times in the database to unix timestamp. But in lucene, how will I do it? And if I store those startTime and finishTimes in the database as unix timestamp value, users timestamp will never occur between them as user's timestamp is the recent timestamp. Sir, if my understanding is wrong, please clarify me.

Comment: My mistake, I thought that `time` referred to a specific point in history (i.e. a "date-time" value, not a "time of day" value), but in any event the approach is still valid. When building your Lucene documents convert the time from "hh:mm tt" into a seconds count `(HH * 60 * 60) + ( mm * 60 )` and the search strategy will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to the ISO 8601 "brief" format will also work ("20130328T144734" or somesuch).